# Making project, I got Project Configuration Exception on console

Tags: android-studio

I got this error when I try to building in the console also in the event log I got some error. I don't know why.

Event log:

24/04/2019
13:35   Gradle sync started

13:36   Gradle sync failed: Cause: startup failed:
            build file 'C:\Users\PC\Dropbox\Programacion\androidstudio\primera app\build.gradle': 7: unexpected token: ... @ line 7, column 9.
            ...
            ^
            1 error
            Consult IDE log for more details (Help | Show Log) (15 s 244 ms)

14:12   Gradle sync started

14:12   Gradle sync failed: Cause: startup failed:
            build file 'C:\Users\PC\Dropbox\Programacion\androidstudio\primera app\build.gradle': 7: unexpected token: ... @ line 7, column 9.
            ...
            ^
            1 error
            Consult IDE log for more details (Help | Show Log) (672 ms)

14:15   Executing tasks: [assemble]

14:15   Gradle build finished in 329 ms

14:15   Gradle sync started

14:15   Gradle sync failed: Cause: startup failed:
            build file 'C:\Users\PC\Dropbox\Programacion\androidstudio\primera app\build.gradle': 7: unexpected token: ... @ line 7, column 9.
            ...
            ^
            1 error
            Consult IDE log for more details (Help | Show Log) (669 ms)

14:16   Executing tasks: [assemble]

14:16   Gradle build finished in 174 ms

startup failed:
build file 'C:\Users\PC\Dropbox\Programacion\androidstudio\primera app\build.gradle': 7: unexpected token: ... @ line 7, column 9.
           ...
           ^

1 error

Open File

I have tried to solve this error but I don't find any fail in the file.

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        // Gradle 4.1 and higher include support for Google's Maven repo using
        // the google() method. And you need to include this repo to download
        // Android Gradle plugin 3.0.0 or higher.
        google()
        ...
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.0'
    }
}
```

Comment: It says your build.gradle has an error on line 7. It encounters an unexpected token. Could you share the relevant part of your build.gradle?

Comment: What is the relevant part? In the three points below google() I got a sintax error if I erase the three points I got more errors.

Comment: I thought you left out some parts of the build.gradle. Indeed, you've got a syntax error on the three dots. What does it say when you remove those dots and rebuild your project?